# Adding a tag synonym

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

In a comment to this [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2776/having-a-self-published-publication-properly-peer-reviewed) the OP asked for a "reviewing" tag. Charles correctly pointed out that we already have a "peer-review" tag. It seems like "reviewing", however, could be a tag synonym for "peer review". I thought I would give creating a tag synonym a go as I recently got that magic power. I read the [stack overflow instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)  about how to make a tag synonym. It seems the tag needs to be in the system already. So do I tag the relevant question "reviewing", and then create a synonym?

Comment: I think that, by default, if you have the privileges and you think it's a good idea, then you should do it :) (I personally don't have any strong feeling either way).

Comment: @CharlesMorisset that was my plan, but the question is how to do it.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, well, I don't know much more than you do, although it seems that this feature is rather used when there is a confusion between existing tags rather than to add a new one. You could however create it on some relevant questions, and then make the tags synonyms.